# Sublevel dropdown Menu using Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, css, twitter, twitter-bootstrap

I have this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/xkXdy/

I want to have submenus for this dropdown Input box. Right now it has the category. I want to have Subcategory upon Mouse Over. Dropdown will trigger when Clicked. (Done). Then when hovered to the category which has Subcategory, it would show its subcategories.

Help please. Thank you in adv.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Do you know that nested select lists are really tricky to style? Is this the best way to represent your data?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here i have done complete solution for above issue. you can check demo link here...

**DEMO** http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqp6z

**HTML**

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
<li class="active"><a href="#">Regular link</a></li>
<li class="dropdown">
  <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="menu1">
    <li>
        <a href="#">2-level Menu <i class="icon-arrow-right"></i></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li class="nav-header">Nav header</li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
<li class="dropdown">
  <a href="#">Menu</a>
</li>
<li class="dropdown">
  <a href="#">Menu</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.dropdown-menu .sub-menu {
  left: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  margin-top: -1px;
}

.dropdown-menu li:hover .sub-menu {
  visibility: visible;
  display: block;
}

.navbar .sub-menu:before {
  border-bottom: 7px solid transparent;
  border-left: none;
  border-right: 7px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-top: 7px solid transparent;
  left: -7px;
  top: 10px;
}
.navbar .sub-menu:after {
  border-top: 6px solid transparent;
  border-left: none;
  border-right: 6px solid #fff;
  border-bottom: 6px solid transparent;
  left: 10px;
  top: 11px;
  left: -6px;
}
```

**DEMO** http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqp6z

Comment: I don't understand how the demo works. I can't select items

Answer (score 6):

Try this 
Working demo http://jsfiddle.net/xkXdy/6/

html

```
<div class="dropdown">
                        <ul>  

                            <li class="dropdown" id="accountmenu" style="list-style: none;">  
                                <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                                <input type="text" placeholder="">                        
                                <b class="caret"></b></a>  
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">  

                                         <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                                             <a tabindex="-1" href="#">PHP options</a>
                                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">

                                         <li><a href="#">PHP-sub</a></li>  

                                          <li><a href="#">PHP-sub2</a></li>
                                      </ul>   
                                </li>                                   
                                    <li><a href="#">MySQL</a></li>  
                                    <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>  
                                    <li><a href="#">HTML5</a></li>  
                                </ul>  
                            </li>  
            </ul>          </div>
```

JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
        $(document).ready(function () {  
            $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();  
        });  
   </script>
```